# How do you know which substitutions to make to cancel out a term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

I am doing problem B45 from Ivan Niven's "Maxima and Minima Without Calculus" which says:

"Consider the quadratic polynomial $f(x, y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+cy+k$ , where the coefficients are real constants with $a>0$ and $c>0$ . In case $b \not =0$ , verify that the transformation $x=X-by/a$ produces a quadratic polynomial $f(X-by/a , y)$ with no $Xy$ term."

The reason why he didn't want an $Xy$ terms is because if there is none then the function is easy to minimize by minimizing the two variables separately. My question is, what steps led to the substitution $x=X-by/a$? How did he know that making this substitution would lead you to having no $Xy$ term? How can this method be extended more generally to other functions? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this part of conic section?

Comment: Didn't you try to replace and see what exactly happens? Then you might get some insight about why that substitution was done.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yea I know that the Xy term disapears and I can see that if we have no Xy term the function is easy to minimize, but I was asking how did he know what to substitute to make the Xy term disappear. For example, how did he know to make the substitution $x=X-by/a$ , when he could've tried something like $x=X-bc^2/4ay$? Was it trial and error?

Comment: @sidht it looks like it

Comment: It is called completing the square. You have done it lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is called (for quadratics) *completing the square*. You have done it often, though probably mostly with explicit numbers. We can write the quadratic part as 
$$a\left(x^2+2\frac{b}{a}xy +\frac{c}{a}y^2\right).$$
Rewrite this as 
$$\frac{1}{a}\left(\left(x+\frac{b}{a}y\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}y^2+\frac{c}{a}y^2\right).$$
The substitution $X=x+\frac{b}{a}y$ is now natural.

**Remark:** Variants of the completing the square idea show up all over. To get away from squares, consider the cubic equation $x^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$. A step in "Cardano's" solution of the cubic was to make the equivalent of the substitution $x=t-\frac{b}{3}$.

When we do the substitution, we end up with a cubic equation of the shape $t^3+et+f=0$, with no term in $t^2$.

Comment: Hah thanks I wouldn't have thought about it +1

Answer (score 2):

I would say that he decided to make a linear substitution of the form $x=X+\lambda y$ (or equivalently $X = x-\lambda y$) and then figured out what the $Xy$ term would be after the substitution. Careful choice of $\lambda$ (in this case $\lambda=-b/a$) made that coefficient $0$.

It's not trial and error at the level of what substitution to make, but it is, to some extent, trial and error at the level of what type of substitution to make.

Comment: Good answer, but how did he know the substitution should be linear? Is that the trial and error part?

Comment: I think he wasn't certain in advance that a linear substitution would work, but it is one of the easiest possible substitutions, so would be a reasonable first try (assuming that one came up with the idea of make a substitution at all).